# php: Redirection limit reached

Tags: php, cross-domain, file-get-contents

I'm running the following loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 30; $i++) {
    sleep(2);
    $content = file_get_contents('http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444528825');
}
```

Basically, I'm running a cronjob (every one minute, 30 times) that gets data from a json file. The file that I'm receiving is being updated automatically. When there is no data it's empty, if there is data it has data in it..

So basically when the file is empty I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534443): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
```

That's ok and understandable, but the problem is that sometimes, I get this error instead:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534451): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
```

I searched it up but I didn't find any reason for the second error to appear. What can I do? **Is there a smarter way to write this script or avoid getting the error?**

Example of error log:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534443): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
 in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534445): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
 in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534447): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
 in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534449): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
 in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534451): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534454): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534456): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534458): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534460): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534462): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534464): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534466): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534468): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534470): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534500): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1444534502): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/dupdates/domains/dupdates.com/public_html/systems/history/script.php on line 60
```

Comment: @charlietfl will it make the error not occur? Will it fix it?

Comment: API gives you error handling capabilities

Comment: @charlietfl OK, I will try using cURL and see if it works, thanks for the advice! I will update you soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used curl instead:

```
<?php
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/Alert/alerts.json?v=1'); 

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```